# AirPrint and uiactionsheet - HOW?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactionsheet, airprint

I created an actionsheet that is called when a button on the navigation bar is pressed. It displays 3 buttons (send to email, print and cancel). 
Now I don't know how to make the iPhone print the uiwebview when the "print" button in the actionsheet is pressed. Can anyone help me ? Or maybe has some sample code for me? 
I am using the latest Xcode 4.3 with storyboard and programming for iphone.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Use ActivitySheet instead...

```
        UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"]; //the image you want to print
        NSArray *itemsToShare = @[yourImage];
        UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo]; //or whichever you don't need >>> in this case we just have AirPrint
        [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```